# Error: argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type double precision

Tags: postgresql, arguments, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to execute this query in PostgreSQL

```
  SELECT sum(No_of_Items) AS Total,
         Name FROM All_Bills_of_POS
GROUP BY Name
  HAVING MAX(Total)
ORDER BY Total DESC LIMIT 1";
```

But I'm getting this error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type double precision

But this query works fine in SQLite. How to execute it in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HAVING clause doesn't evaluate to boolean. I think you need something like:

```
SELECT sum(No_of_Items) AS Total, Name 
FROM All_Bills_of_POS 
GROUP BY Name 
HAVING MAX(Total) > 1
ORDER BY Total DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The `HAVING MAX(Total)` should have some condition.  For e.g.

`HAVING MAX(Total) > 100`

This condition should return a boolean, i.e. true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since your are retrieving a single row, the `name` with the most items (biggest `sum(No_of_Items)`), you don't need the `HAVING` clause at all. Drop it:

```sql
SELECT sum(No_of_Items) AS Total, Name
FROM   All_Bills_of_POS
GROUP  BY Name
HAVING MAX(Total)
ORDER  BY Total DESC, Name  -- tiebreaker
LIMIT  1;
```

I also add `Name` as additional `ORDER BY` item, to break ties in a deterministic fashion: If multiple names tie for the maximum, the alphabetically first wins.

If your objective is something else, you should share it with us in the question (which you should do in any case).